# How does John Constantine earn a living?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, constantine-2014

As far as I can tell, we don’t see John Constantine earn any money for his work as a “master of the dark arts”, but he somehow supports a lifestyle with a large home, an extensive collection of rare artifacts, and many travel expenses. Where does his money come from?

I’m picturing Arrowverse John Constantine, but I’m happy to hear if there are answers from the comics or the earlier movie.

Comment: If enough people owe you, then why worry about money ;)

Comment: In the comics, I recall him stealing money from corpses, shoplifting, earning it by working as a private dick, pawning artifacts he's recovered from supernatural beings. Y'know, bits and bobs.

Comment: In the Arrowverse his (large) apartment was apparently won from someone *"Are you guys from Housing co-op? Because it's perfectly legal to win an apartment in a duel."* - https://subslikescript.com/series/Legends_of_Tomorrow-4532368/season-3/episode-15-Necromancing_the_Stone

Comment: And he doesn't seem to be above performing magical rituals for cash. 

**JC:** *It's a gig economy. I have to take the work where I can find it, you know?*

Comment: It seems that he borrows a fair amount of money. On several occasions he skips out on drinks and it's stated in *Genesis* that he owes Chas cash. "**Chas:** *Tell John Constantine he still owes me money.*"

Comment: Nah, he earns a killing!

Comment: He is been "shopping" in cursed tombs for years. And it's not that magical nor cursed enought, it may just be on craig list.
In fact even if it's power full enought to have a special place on shelf in a major magician house/tower, if someone is willin to buy he would be selling even if it's not his item in the first place.

Comment: I've wondered this about a lot of people in the Arrowverse. Some I get, like Team Arrow because Oliver Queen is a bajillionaire, but what about Team Flash or the Legends? Granted, I haven't read the comics either.

Comment: @Valorum. With how meanings in modern day English have changed, that third one might need a bit of disambiguation :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist - You're crazy as a couple of waltzing mice.

Answer (score 40):

The easiest way to reply is by his nickname that his friends call him:

### Con-Job

In his illustrious career John "Helllblazer" Constantine had quite a few sources of income:

- Performing in a punk group

  [image]
- Working as PI/Occult detective

  [image]
- Exorcist for hire
  [image]
- Performing magical rituals for money, going as far as putting a demon into a corpse of a child (he was forced to do that, but he wasn't above taking money for it)

  [image]
- Blackmailing rich people

  [image]
- **Pretending** to do magical rituals for money

  [image]
- Cheating when gambling

  [image]
- Conjuring fake money /making people believe that he has paid them

[image]

- Petty theft

[image]

- Borrowing money and not paying back <sup>1</sup>
- Using his friends to pay for him

Its worth to point that John doesn't care much about having money - he once spent whole year as a homeless person. His usual needs are quite basic: place to sleep, something to drink and a pack of smokes.

<sup>1. Quite a few of his friends complain that "John owes them money". He is also quite happy to make them pay for his drinks, usually even without asking them first.</sup>